# Editing Text File to remove everything before certain character

Tags: python, text, python-3.6

So I'm creating a fake chat generator, I've gotten chatlogs of Twitch streams to make a massive chatlog text file. However they're formatted like this,

```
[2017-10-14 05:27:17 UTC] beboh13: is this guy good
```

Is there a way to make a Python script to edit every line to remove the 4th space, so the message above would turn into this?

```
is this guy good
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or a code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: Okay then, sorry if I caused any inconvenience. :)

Comment: I think you need the **split()** method. Once you know how to use this built-in **spilt()** method, it will be lot easier :) [Read about it here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved my problem, you don't actually have to use Python, I just got my text editor, did CTRL+H to bring up the replace menu, made sure that the special command thingys were on. (The button was a picture of `.*`) Then did `.*UTC] .*:` to replace with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your logfile to a csv format and do the following

```
In [3]: import csv

In [3]: with open('twitch.csv','r') as file:
    reado = csv.reader(file, delimiter= ' ') 
    #make sure that the delimiter in the file is a space
    for row in reado:
        print(' '.join(row[4:]))
```